# Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 fresh install unable to connect to security. & us.archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: networking, apt, server, updates, update-manager

After having run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS for a (short) while, I've just replaced it with a CLI Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS. The installation included `Samba` and `OpenSSH`. The only thing I've done so far, after the installation finished, was to set up the ethernet NIC, as the laptop running this OS is connected via an ethernet cable to the router. It gets an IPv4 static address and an IPv6 auto (DHCP6-provided) address.

It can `ping` the gateway (router) and other LAN PC's — but every `ping` attempt on anything beyond that, returns:

```
Packet filtered
```

And results in a 100% packet loss. I suspect that the system as-is has no internet connectivity actually, but I don't know either how to confirm this — or, as the next logical step, how to eventually rectify it.

Now, the very next thing I did was to execute

```
sudo apt update
```

Where I got four error messages, their content being:

```
Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
```

The error messages refer to 4 repositories:

```
The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release' does not have a Release file
The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file
The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release' does not have a Release file
The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports Release' does not have a Release file
```

Please advise on how to deal with the matter, and thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: can you `ping 8.8.8.8`?  Can you `ping google.com`?  Can you run `curl -I --header "Host: security.ubuntu.com" http://91.189.88.152/ubuntu/` and get a "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" response in the output?  If you can, can you retry the update step on your system again?  (It could have been a transient network issue).  Also, do you have any sort of proxy on your network or restriction preventing your system from reaching directly outbound?

Comment: I cannot ping either 8.8.8.8 or google.com; I get all "Packet filtered" and 100% packet loss.
The curl command returns the following error message: `(7) Failed to connect to 91.189.88.152 port 80: No route to host`

Comment: it sounds like your router is blocking traffic, and you need to look at your router to solve the problem.  (which would be beyond the scope of Ask Ubuntu technically...)

Answer (score 0):

Further troubleshooting proved that it was eventually a router issue, like Thomas Ward had suggested. After re-configuring the lan port on the router, everything works like a charm.